# Return multiple types from single method in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, return-value

I am working on a basic game and 2D engine in Xna/C# and I am trying to simplify a few things in it.  I have a base class of Entity2D from the engine and two classes specific to the game that inherit from it: Tower and Enemy.  In my engine, rather than having two separate lists, one for Towers and one for Enemies I would like to combine them together into a single generic list.  I then I have the problem of when I need to return a Tower from the list or an Enemy from the list.  I know that I can use typecasting from the engine object:

```
class Entity2D {...} //engine object
class Tower : Entity2D {...} //game specific
class Enemy : Entity2D {...} //game specific

//In engine:
public Entity2D GetEntity(int index) { ...return objects[index];}

//Somewhere in the game
{
    Enemy e = GetEntity(0) as Enemy;
    if(e != null)
        //Enemy returned

    Tower t = GetEntity(0) as Tower;
    if(t != null)
        //Tower returned
}
```

Of course this seems really inefficient.

I have also looked into the `is` keyword a bit, and it seems that works like so:

```
Entity2D entity = GetEntity(0);
if(entity is Tower)
{
    Tower t = (Tower)entity;
    t.DoTowerThings();
}
```

Still that results in returning a base object and using even more memory to create a second object and typecast into it.

What would really be nice is if there is a way to do something like this:

```
//In engine:
public T GetEntity(int index) 
{ 
    if(T == Tower) //or however this would work: (T is Tower), (T as Tower), etc
        return objects[index] as Tower;
    else if(T == Enemy) 
        return objects[index] as Enemy;
    else return null;
}

Enemy e = GetEntity(0);
```

But then that breaks the engine portion of having the engine and game be seperate

I am looking for the clearest as well as most memory efficient way to go about this while still having Entity2D be engine based and avoid having Tower or Enemy in the engine at all.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you intend to do in this method?

Comment: Why do you want to combine the 2 `Entity2d` lists into one list? It doesn't seem like they have any relation to each other except they share the same base. Keep them separate and avoid this whole situation.

Comment: If you want a precisely typed result there are no other options. But what about `public T Get<T>(int index) { return engine.GetEntity(index) as T; }`? That would enable `var e = Get<Enemy>(0)` without messing with the engine. Keep in mind that `is` and `as` incur a small runtime cost but not memory usage.

Comment: @DaveZych: If you keep them separate then the engine has to know about all the concrete types of entities you are going to use, which means you cannot reuse it for the next game.

Comment: Provide an interface that the engine knows about. That should sort things out. e.g. `IEntity`, `IMovable:IEntity`, `IGameObject:IEntity`

Comment: @LewsTherin: `Entity2D` is already such an interface. Will expanding it solve the problem? Why? How in particular should it be expanded?

Comment: @Jon `Entity2D` is a class and I don't know how it works. But I think using `Entity2D` as a central repository store all game entities is asking for pain in the future. Provide an interface for each entity type, and maybe a repository for an interface. Anything to make life/maintenance easy.

Comment: @LewsTherin: So you are in effect saying "keep separate lists". I don't know how `Entity2D` works either, but I also don't see how `Enemy : Entity2D, IEntity` would help. This is enriching the public interface of `Enemy`, but the problem was not caused by not having a rich enough interface.

Comment: @Jon I wouldn't let `Enemy : Entity2D`, more like `Entity2D.DoSomething(IEntity)` if that makes sense. Let the `Entity2D` work on an entity without knowing too much about the entity.. However you have a lot of experience than I, so you are seeing something I can't :P

Comment: @LewsTherin: That's the Visitor pattern, which has its uses and might actually be a good fit for this scenario. Unfortunately it requires **major** code reorganization and lots of explanation.

Comment: @Jon I just had a look at it on Wikipedia and you are indeed right. Hopefully when the OP has time he can learn about it for future cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there!

```
//In engine:
public T GetEntity<T>(int index) where T : Entity2D
{ 
    return objects[index] as T;
}
//Somewhere else:
Enemy e = GetEntity<Enemy>(0);
```

Note: if `objects[index]` is NOT a `T`, it will return `null` instead.

However, if it was my game, I would just keep separate lists for each type of object.

Comment: To rephrase, what if `objects[0]` is `Tower`?

Comment: @LewsTherin It would return null.

Comment: Yeah, not really the best. I think you should show the way you would do it.. though that might be a pita.

Comment: @LewsTherin Do you think the OP would rather have an `InvalidCastException` instead?

Comment: Of course not, unless if that's the way you'd do it: "I think you should show the way you would do it.."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, ([full code on Github](https://github.com/brunolm/StackOverflow/blob/master/StackOverflow/Return-multiple-types-from-single-method-in-c-sharp.cs))

```
public T GetEntity<T>(int index) where T : Entity2D
{
    return list.ElementAt(index) as T;
}
```

If the element is not the expected type it will return null.

```
Tower t = GetEntity<Tower>(0);
```

Comment: `ElementAt` when you've got an array? What?

Comment: He said list, and `ElementAt` will work with any `IEnumerable` type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx

Comment: I am aware of that, however if he's already shown some code with an indexer, he must be using a collection with an indexer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to disambiguate the return value, then the structure of the code is bad, the objects are not logically similar and you would be better off having two lists with a separate accessor for each type.

However, if the types are very similar and you only need to disambiguate between them rarely, then do this:-

```
abstract class GameEntity : Entity2D
{
  abstract public void TowerOnlyFunction (args); // need to look up exact syntax, but you get the idea
  abstract public void EnemyOnlyFunction (args);

  void CommonFunctions (args);
}

class Tower : GameEntity
{
  public void TowerOnlyFunction (args)
  {
    // code
  }
  public void EnemyOnlyFunction (args)
  {
    // empty
  }
}

class Enemy : GameEntity
{
  public void TowerOnlyFunction (args)
  {
    // empty
  }
  public void EnemyOnlyFunction (args)
  {
    // code
  }
}

//Somewhere in the game
void DoSomethingWithTower ()
{
  GameEntity e = GetEntity(0);
  e.TowerOnlyFunction ();
}
```